# PhpStorm won't resolve includes using constants

Tags: php, phpstorm

This used to work, but it stopped working recently. I don't think anything changed in my settings, but I have poured over them for a couple hours now just to make sure. I have checked all over google and SO too. Please pay attention to the details before claiming "this was answered over here..." Thanks. :)

---

**Assumptions and Requirements**

Assume we have two files:

- `<project_root>/index.php`
- `<project_root>/folder/file.php`

Assume our project root is `/home/me/project`.

We want to include file.php from index.php. We expect PhpStorm to be able to resolve the file path and allow us to do nifty IDE things like "Go To Declaration."

**What works**

```php
    require 'folder/file.php';

    require '/home/me/project/folder/file.php';

    $root = '/home/me/project/';
    require $root.'folder/file.php';
```

**What No Longer Works**

```php
    define('ROOT_DIR', "/home/me/project/");
    require ROOT_DIR.'folder/file.php';
```

PhpStorm *does* recognize the value of `ROOT_DIR` when I mouseover, but it highlights `home` and says something like: `Path '"/home/me...folder/file.php' not found`

**Why Use a Constant Anyway?**
To keep this simple, I've left out details that are not necessary to illustrate the problem. The primary thing I'd like to address is why this used to work but no longer does, and/or how can I make it work again.

---

**Sorry, can't help. What are you *really* trying to do?**
Here are the details I left out. If we can't solve the primary issue, perhaps we can find a good work around.

I'm working with an existing codebase. Most files require a `config.php` file that defines `root_dir()` for getting the web/project root. PhpStorm wasn't resolving those paths (understandably so), so I created a constant to takes it's place. That makes more sense anyway.

In today's battle, I discovered that you can do this:

```php
    /** @define "root_dir()" "/home/me/project/" */
    // or
    /** @define "ROOT_DIR" "/home/me/project/" */
```

If you put that anywhere in the file then PhpStorm is able to resolve all the includes/requires in that file. BUT, it only works in that file, even if you try to include/require it in another file. You'd have to do this to EVERY file to get it working everywhere. Nope. Nuh-uh. No thank you. I need to reference the absolute path to the project/web root in a way that PhpStorm will recognize across the whole project.

Comment: Also note: PhpStorm updated recently.

Comment: It's a bug in latest PhpStorm v2016.1.1. They recently were working on constants and/or include improvements ([possibly this one](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-30953)).. and this must be some side effect of it (a regression). *Possibly* this ticket (not 100% sure as I do not use include/require myself) - https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-31638

Comment: Another possible ticket: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-31754

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@LazyOne answered this in the comments. This is a bug in the latest release, and it's being tracked here: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-31754

Comment: 3 years later and I found this answer because I have the same problem. Do we have any info about the progress of that bug? Because it seems to still persist...
Using PhpStorm 2020.1

Comment: This exact issue has been fixed. Could you post another question with your specific details? I'd be happy to take a look if you post the link here. :)

Answer (score 0):

Until this gets patched I've created this work around:

Using [Keyboard Maestro](https://www.keyboardmaestro.com/main/), I created a hotkey that will paste the `@define` comment at the top of the file and return the cursor to its original position. [Download  the macro here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1267008/PHP%20-%20root_dir%28%29%20fix.kmmacros). Import that and edit the text.

Edit: You may actually need to edit the file in a regular text editor. One of the file paths may need to be changed to work on your system.

Note: I'm using a modified version of the Mac Eclipse keyboard layout in PHPStorm. I'm not sure that will matter.

Also, be aware that many of your "changed files" will simply have this mapping at the top of the file, and this mapping may not be correct for you teammates. I'm simply excluding those changes from my commits.